# MVC Kendo UI DropdownListFor

Tags: c#, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm having a issue with Kendo UI when I try to use DropdownListFor, this is my first time using this tool, so when I try to create a component with this helper, the component is being created instead a textbox is created, this is my code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.property)
              .DataTextField("Text")
              .DataValueField("Value")
              .Events(e => e.Change("change"))
              .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
                      new SelectListItem() {
                           Text = "Black",
                           Value = "1"
                      },
                      new SelectListItem() {
                          Text = "Orange",
                          Value = "2"
                      },
                      new SelectListItem() {
                          Text = "Grey",
                          Value = "3"
                      }})
                      .Value("1")
                      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" }))
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: "when I try to create a component, the component is being created instead a textbox is created" can you please explain what it means ?

Comment: at the moment when UI is created I'm not getting a dropdown, the UI is creating a textbox and not a dropdown

Comment: Are there any script errors showing in the browser console?

Comment: No there is no errors in the console right now!

Comment: What is the type of `m.property`?

Comment: is type int, but I already saw was the issue was, there was an old page that use the same property for a dropdown also, so that was creating a conflict, that old page is no longer needed so when I removed the issue was also removed and the dropdown was working fine! Thanks guys!